# Chunked transfer encoding problems in weblogic. I do not know how to configure weblogic in order to get an jsp image not chunked

Tags: jsp, encoding, weblogic, transfer, chunked

I have a simple jsp file that calls an jsp image with this line:
`<img src='captcha.jsp' id='captcha'>`

The problem is that this image is not loaded properly. I have problems with weblogic with chunked encoding.

I tested this in Tomcat and Glasfish and i do not have problems.
I have searched through the net and i do not know how to configure weblogic. I tried to change parameters in the weblogic console but i couldn't succeed.

I have tried as well differents approaches in the jsp file. Using things as
response.setContentLength but is not working.

Finally, I have changed the property `ChunkedTransferDisabled = "true"` but it is not working. I do not know why it is not working now

Can you please help me or clarify my ideas.

Thank you very much.

Captcha.jsp

We create the image

```
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();

//Some stuff
```

then write

```
Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(imageFormat);
            if( iter.hasNext() ) {
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
            ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

            if ( imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg") ) {
                iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                iwp.setCompressionQuality(imageQuality);
            }

            writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()));
            IIOImage imageIO = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
            writer.write(null, imageIO, iwp);

            } 

        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("no encoder found for jsp");
        }

        // Colocamos el string en la sesión
        request.getSession().setAttribute("captcha", finalString.toString());

        g.dispose();
```

Comment: Could you post your code that generates the image?

Comment: Thank you but finally it is solved. I added a new answer.

Comment: Why is it a problem that it's chunked?

Comment: The problem was that all browsers couldn't display the image. I think that the content-length was completly full and the image couldn't be sent. I suppose it is a weblogic bug, maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem. The image was not sent properly because the buffer was full or i do not know why. There was no problem about chunked encoding. I think that the problem was that content-length header was full, maybe weblogic bug.

Just adding `response.resetBuffer()` at the beggining of captcha.jsp solved the problem.